# Ajax send json to spring boot server and open generated pdf in new tab

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-boot, pdfbox

I have small web application, which collects data from form, sends it via Ajax to spring boot server. Server generates pdf file and sends it back as byte array. Then I want a PDF to be opened in new tab butI see empty PDF there and that is my problem.
This is the Ajax method:

```
function sendJson(json) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/pdf/create",
    type: "POST",
    data: json,
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Success');

        openFile(data)
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log('Was trying to send data, but error occurred. ' + json);
        alert('Error sending data to server');
    }
});
}
```

Then I create a blob from data received and open it.

```
function openFile(byte) {
    var file = new Blob([byte], {type: "application/pdf"});

    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    window.open(fileURL);
}
```

This is my spring boot controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/pdf/create")
public ResponseEntity<?> preparePdf(@RequestBody String data) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Data input: " + data);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> dataObject = mapper.readValue(data, Map.class);

    try {
        return pdfService.createPdfFromTemplate(dataObject);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Processing goes here:

```
public ResponseEntity<Resource> createPdfFromTemplate(Map<String, Object> dataObject) throws IOException {

// data saved to DB. PDF is generated and saved locally

    String filename = "generated_file.pdf";

    File pdf = new File(filename);
    byte[] fileBytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(pdf);

    ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder res = ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

            return res.body(new ByteArrayResource(fileBytes));
}
```

The text in generated pdf is cyrillic but I don't think the problem lies here, or some encoding.
I think I'm missing something important here. Sometimes I see opinions that it can't be done via ajax or POST method is not a good way, but it seems logical to send json data and receive generated file back. Any ideas appreciated guys.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will be useful for someone. I encoded my byte array into base64 String on server side using `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileBytes)` as a body to my response. In JS before opening a file I converted it to ArrayBuffer like this:

```
function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binaryString = window.atob(base64);
    var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
    for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

And file is opened in a new tab as I expected.